# how does this line in structure execute?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *link;
};
```

this is for the linked list using the concept of pointers and structure. I want to know how and why we are making the pointer of the node structure.

Comment: Each node in a linked list contains a pointer to the next node (or `NULL` if it is the end of the chain).

Answer (score 1):

In a linked list, you have a chain of nodes point to the next.

```
head
+----------+       +----------+       +----------+       +----------+
|       ---------->|data:  123|   +-->|data:  456|   +-->|data:  789|
+----------+       +----------+   |   +----------+   |   +----------+
                   |link: --------+   |link: --------+   |link: NULL|
                   +----------+       +----------+       +----------+
```

(`link` is more typically called `next`.)